# Showing SAT is auto-reducible

Tags: turing-machines, oracle-machines, sat-solvers

I am trying to wrap my head around the concepts of *auto-reducibility* and *having access to an Oracle*.
The way I understand is that a language is auto-reducible iff there is a Turing Machine $M^{L}(x)=1$ for every *x $\in$ L* with the special requirement that on input *x* the Turing Machine is not allowed to query the Oracle for x.

Does that mean it can query anything else?

For example in the case of SAT, we can then query the Oracle for *x $\land$ True*, which would be a different input, however it would still include the entirety of *x*.  Would that be allowed?

Answer (score 2):

Autoreducibility was introduced in Buhrman, Fortnow and Torenvliet, [Using autoreducibility to separate complexity classes](https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/1930/1930D.pdf). Here is the (informal) definition (page 520):

> A set $L$ is autoreducible if there is a polynomial-time oracle Turing machine $M$ that accepts $L$ using $L$ as an oracle with the caveat that $M(x)$ may not query whether $x \in L$.

Comment: Thank you for the source but does that mean I can query in case of SAT x & True?